# What is the simplest circuit which can automatically power on a V59 LCD controller?

Tags: switches, lcd

Given a V59 LCD controller, what is the simplest circuit that would automatically power on the LCD once voltage to the red LED becomes present?  The goal is to automatically turn on the monitor once power is supplied to the LCD controller ( currently it does not and instead awaits for someone to press the power button controlled by K0 in the schematic ).

Specifications can be found here:  https://sites.google.com/site/lcd4hobby/6-lcd-as-pc-vga-hdmi-av-tv-display-tsumv59/ND-LA.MV9.P-2.pdf

> Page 7 shows the "Key Schematic" referring to K0 and LEDR

I'm assuming there would likely need to be a slight delay before closing the K0 circuit after voltage is detected on LEDR to turn on the monitor.

Would a capacitor for delay and a transistor for switching be able to handle these requirements?

Comment: No, because k0 is a momentary input. Any number of ICs may be able to do this. Voltage supervisors. A flip flop. A 555 timer? But frankly, throw a 10 cent microcontroller at it instead. Nothing that 5 minutes of code can't handle.

Comment: I's hard to know what that device will do.  I'd start by wiring K0 to ground and seeing what effect that has,  then if that does not work try K0 to LED_G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the data sheet, K0 is the power button by default.  So, all you need to do is simulate a momentary closure to ground. A simple 555 timer should work. Trigger it with the LEDR level and connect the normally high output of the timer to K0.

Comment: Thank you @Guill - Seems perfectly reasonable to me.  Unless I hear otherwise, will likely go with this setup - Wanted to be sure.  Thanks again